# How to make grunt run some tasks at a special point in time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, gruntjs, automated-tests

I am using Grunt to run Jasmine tests and Nightwatch.js tests. Is it possible to make Grunt run the tests at a special point in time? For example Grunt could run the tests always when saving changed code. Or Grunt could run the tests always at 1 am in the morning. Is that possible and how?

Comment: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch, it watches when ever the changes have been made on the targeted file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) makes you to do some task when the inspected file has changed.
2. [grunt-crontab](https://github.com/joerx/grunt-crontab) can let you do some task at specific time, just like crontab.
   e.g in grunt setting:

grunt-crontab example.

```
{
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "command": YOUR COMMAND,
      "schedule": "0 1 * * *",  //Every day's 1:00 A.M.
      "comments": YOUR COMMENTS.
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit:
Currently grunt-crontab just Add the commands to crontab for you, means it's not able to watch the result directly, the preferable way is use grunt-contrib-watch to monitor the changes.

Comment: and what exactly do I have to write as YOUR COMMAND? e.g. `'grunt jasminetest'`?

Comment: Yes, but you need to give command like `cd <%= project.baseDir %> && grunt`, and all the grunt-crontab do is : Put the command to crontab :P, that means you can't watch the result whether the jasminetest is pass or not, maybe you should just use grunt-contrib-watch.

Comment: this means i cannot use this for testing, because i cannot see the results?

Comment: Yes, as I tested, it just create a crontab task for you, so unless you log it, you can't see results, but even if you log it, you still need to view the log yourself, so I suggest not use `grunt-crontab` for testing.